# AutoML Tables Batch Prediction- Produces an empty table in google big query

Tags: google-bigquery, prediction, forecasting, google-cloud-vertex-ai

I am new to google cloud platform's Vertex AI. In Vertex AI I have created a new batch prediction and would like a Bigquery output table. However when I create the new batch prediction the output table is empty. I am not sure what the issue is. Any advise please?

[image]

Comment: Can you add more details like 1.) How did you create a batch prediction request (via Cloud console or via API)? 2.) If via console, can you show how did you setup the batch prediction job? 3.) If via API can you show your code on creating the batch prediction request? 4.) Can you share relevant logs about the created batch prediction job which can be seen in your projects' Cloud Logging.

Comment: @RiccoD I have added an image of how I created the bacth prediction request. Does that help?

Comment: I tried sending a batch prediction using my model and I was able to see the created tables (they are named in this manner "predictions_timestamp") in the BQ dataset I specified in the config. The model is created based from the [example found in the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/tutorials/tabular-automl/dataset-train). I used a CSV file from Cloud Storage as an input. See batch prediction results on [table created](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vhw6u.png).

Comment: Did you try sending an online prediction and got results? Did you follow the input requirements as mentioned in this [document](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/predictions/batch-predictions#tabular)? Did the batch prediction job returned an error? This could be seen in Vertex AI > Batch predictions and check the job name.

Comment: @RiccoD, Hi, thanks, yes the batch prediction job returned an error and this was the error for every row in my testset- "Invalid TIMESTAMP value for timestamp_format "%E4Y-%m-%d": ; Not able to parse timestamp: "" with format: %E4Y-%m-%d."